# Enum NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, communication

I am making a client server communication and one of the messages is a enum. To process of the server side and converted the enum value of the client using a .toString() and on the server side depending on the value received, a variable created gets a enum value. The code is of the server side and the error is on the server protocol:

```
if(x < -type.getLeftInset(rotation) || x + type.getDimension() - type.getRightInset(rotation) >= 10) {
            return false;
        }
```

The code for the server protocol is:

```
package Servidor;


import Servidor.TileType;



// Server side protocol

public class ServerProtocol {


    //HighScore HighScore = null;
    //private HighScore hs;
    DataPlayer dataPlayer;// = null;

    private TileType[][] tiles;

    private int lines, score, newLevel, level;

    private static TileType type;



    public ServerProtocol(){

        TileType type = TileType.TypeJ;


    }



    public boolean MsgValidate(String typeS, int x, int y, int rotation) {



        if(typeS == TileType.TypeI.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeI;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeJ.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeJ;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeL.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeL;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeO.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeO;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeS.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeS;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeT.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeT;
        } 

        if(typeS == TileType.TypeZ.toString()) {
            type = TileType.TypeZ;
        }


        if(x < -type.getLeftInset(rotation) || x + type.getDimension() - type.getRightInset(rotation) >= 10) {
            return false;
        }

        if(y < -type.getTopInset(rotation) || y + type.getDimension() - type.getBottomInset(rotation) >= 22) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int col = 0; col < type.getDimension(); col++) {
            for(int row = 0; row < type.getDimension(); row++) {
                if(type.isTile(col, row, rotation) && isOccupied(x + col, y + row)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }


    private boolean isOccupied(int x, int y) {
        return tiles[y][x] != null;
    }


}
```

The server that calls the server protocol has the code:

```
package Servidor;

import Servidor.TileType;

public class Server implements Runnable {


    public static final String HighScore = null;
    public Socket server = null;

    private TileType[][] tiles;




    public Server(Socket socket){

        this.server = socket;

    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        int port = 6666;

        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Server is listening on port: " + port + "\n\n");

            while(true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Communication accepted: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() /*+ "\n"*/);
                Server server = new Server(socket);
                Thread t = new Thread(server);
                t.start();

            }


        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }


    }




    ServerProtocol Comunicao = new ServerProtocol();

    public void run() {


        ObjectInputStream input;

        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());

            String Msg = (String) input.readObject();
            System.out.println(Msg);

            if (Msg.equals("Start")) {

                System.out.println("Start");



                return;

            }



            if(Msg.equals("Validate")) {

                String typeS = (String) input.readObject();
                System.out.println("Type: " + typeS);

                int x = (int) input.readObject();
                System.out.println("X: " + x);

                int y = (int) input.readObject();
                System.out.println("Y: " + y);

                int rotation = (int) input.readObject();
                System.out.println("Rotation: " + rotation);


                boolean answer = Comunicao.MsgValidate(typeS, x, y, rotation);


                if(answer == false) {

                    System.out.println("Invalid move");
                    ObjectOutputStream saida = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                    saida.writeObject("Invalid move");

                } else if(answer == true) {

                    System.out.println("Valid move");
                    ObjectOutputStream saida = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                    saida.writeObject("Valid move");

                }


            }



        }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }



}
```

I think the error may be because it is nnot initialized but the did it in the beginning of the server protocol code. The error stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Servidor.ServerProtocol.MsgValidate(ServerProtocol.java:224)
    at Servidor.Server.run(Server.java:138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Try using a debugger, or use [helpful NPE](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) to find out what is null.

Comment: The error is on line 224 but the code you provided code has only 92 lines. It would be a big, big help if we new, on which line it crashes. Please mark it with a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is because you're comparing a `java.lang.String` using `==`, which checks for reference equality.
Becuase none of your conditions is met, the variable `type` inside your method `MsgValidate` stays `null`.

To solve this concrete problem, replace all you `==` checks with, for example, `typeS.equals(TileType.TypeI.toString())`. However, there are several other pitfalls in the code you've shown.

## Pitfalls

### ServerProtocol:

1. You're not initializing the member-variable `type` in the constructor. You're just creating a local variable named `type`, which is not used
2. The member-varialbe `type` should just be a local variable inside your `MsgValidate` method
3. You never inititialize your `tiles` array and also never write to it. A tile will never be occupied
4. Your sequence of `if`s can be replaced by a simple for-loop

Suggested changes applied:

```java
package Servidor;


import Servidor.TileType;



// Server side protocol

public class ServerProtocol {

    private static final TileType[] TILE_TYPES = new TileType[]{
        TileType.TypeI, TileType.TypeJ, TileType.TypeL, TileType.TypeO, TileType.TypeS, TileType.TypeT, TileType.TypeZ
    };

    //HighScore HighScore = null;
    //private HighScore hs;
    DataPlayer dataPlayer;// = null;

    private TileType[][] tiles;

    private int lines, score, newLevel, level;



    public ServerProtocol(){
    }



    public boolean MsgValidate(String typeS, int x, int y, int rotation) {
        TileType type = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < TILE_TYPES.length && type == null; i++) {
            if (typeS.equals(TILE_TYPES[i].toString())) {
                type = TILE_TYPES[i];
            }
        }

        if (type == null) {
            // or throw an IllegalArgumentException
            return false;
        }

        if(x < -type.getLeftInset(rotation) || x + type.getDimension() - type.getRightInset(rotation) >= 10) {
            return false;
        }

        if(y < -type.getTopInset(rotation) || y + type.getDimension() - type.getBottomInset(rotation) >= 22) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int col = 0; col < type.getDimension(); col++) {
            for(int row = 0; row < type.getDimension(); row++) {
                if(type.isTile(col, row, rotation) && isOccupied(x + col, y + row)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }


    private boolean isOccupied(int x, int y) {
        if (tiles == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (y < 0 || y >= tiles.length) {
            return false;
        } else if (x < 0 || x >= tiles[y].length) {
            return false;
        }

        return tiles[y][x] != null;
    }
}
```

Also, you should read about some common Java Code Conventions.
For example, packages should be completly lowercase. Methodnames should start with an lowercase letter

Comment: Your solution solved that problem but I encountered another NullPointerException on the isOccupied(int x, int y) on the server protocol. I pretty much want to say that those coordinates aren't occupied. Do you how to fix that problem? Also, what other pitfalls did you find in the code?

Comment: @Peter I've added a few more pitfalls and an explanation. Hope it helps

Comment: Your notes were very helpful. For the third one, upon connection with the server the tiles are initiated in a for loop. Now it runs with no errors but when the server answers "Valid move" the client doesn't continue with the code in which it should update the row and repaint. Can it be related to the connection time? By what I think it should work because the answer from the server gets stored in a variable, the connection is closed and if the answer is valid the client increments the row and repaints. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. Can you believe I was using "==" again insted of .equals()? Ahahah. Thank you, you have been very helpful!!!